# Read many files in parallel and extract data

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, snow

I have 1000 `json` files. And I would like to read them in parallel. I have `4` CPU cores.

I have a character vector which has the names of all the files as following:-

```
cik_files <- list.files("./data/", pattern = ".json")
```

And using this `vector` I load the file and extract the data and add it to the following list:-

```
data <- list()
```

Below is the code for extracting the data:-

```
for(i in 1:1000){
  data1 <- fromJSON(paste0("./data/", cik_files[i]), flatten = TRUE)
  if(("NetIncomeLoss" %in% names(data1$facts$`us-gaap`))){
    data1 <- data1$facts$`us-gaap`$NetIncomeLoss$units$USD
    data1 <- data1[grep("CY20[0-9]{2}$", data1$frame), c(3, 9)]
    try({if(nrow(data1) > 0){
      data1$cik <- strtrim(cik_files[i], 13)
      data[[length(data) + 1]] <- data1
    }}, silent = TRUE)
  }
}
```

This however, takes quite a lot of time. So I was wondering how I can run the code within the for loop but in parallel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What JSON access package are you using, RJSONIO, rjson or jsonlite?

Comment: Use `lapply` on the list instead of a for-loop. `mclapply` can be used from `parallell` to parallelize. Consider using `fread` from `data.table` to read the file.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, i am using jsonlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt to solve the problem in the question. Untested, since there is no data.

### Step 1

First of all, rewrite the loop in the question as a function.

```
f <- function(i, path = "./data", cik_files){
  filename <- file.path(path, cik_files[i])
  data1 <- fromJSON(filename, flatten = TRUE)
  if(("NetIncomeLoss" %in% names(data1$facts$`us-gaap`))){
    data1 <- data1$facts$`us-gaap`$NetIncomeLoss$units$USD
    found <- grep("CY20[0-9]{2}$", data1$frame)
    if(length(found) > 0){
      tryCatch({
        out <- data1[found, c(3, 9)]
        out$cik <- strtrim(cik_files[i], 13)
        out
      },
      error = function(e) e,
      warning = function(w) w)
    } else NULL
  } else NULL
}
```

### Step 2

Now load the package `parallel` and run one of the following, depending on OS.

```
library(parallel)
```

---

```
# Not on Windows
library(jsonlite)
json_list <- mclapply(seq_along(cik_files), f, cik_files = cik_files)
```

---

```
# Windows
ncores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(ncores - 1L)
clusterExport(cl, "cik_files")
clusterEvalQ(cl, "cik_files")
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(jsonlite))

json_list <- parLapply(cl, seq_along(cik_files), f, cik_files = cik_files)

stopCluster(cl)
```

### Step 3

Extract the data from the returned list `json_list`.

```
err <- sapply(json_list, inherits, "error")
warn <- sapply(json_list, inherits, "warning")
ok <- !(err | warn)
json_list[ok]  # correctly read in
```

Comment: Thank you @Rui Barradas, that you made it work even without the data. It is perfect.