# Load multiple JSON files and iterate a function over the loaded objects

Tags: r

I'm looking for a more elegant way of loading multiple JSON files and applying a function to each, before combining all the resulting data frames so that I can do some analysis on the master data frame.

Here's an example of what I currently have:

```
## Load the files
page.1 <- fromJSON(file = "C:\\page-1.json")
page.2 <- fromJSON(file = "C:\\page-2.json")
page.3 <- fromJSON(file = "C:\\page-3.json")

## Call function (args: list name, page number)
results.1 <- myFunction(page.1, 1)
results.2 <- myFunction(page.2, 2)
results.3 <- myFunction(page.3, 3)

## Combine all results
all.results <- rbind(results.1, results.2, results.3)
```

I'm thinking that there must be a way to use a for() loop, but I'm struggling to find a way to get R to create the object and file names.  Something like this psuedo code:

```
## Create object to store results
all.results <- NULL

## Loop through files
for(i in 1:3){

  ## Load the file corresponding to i
  page.i <- fromJSON(file = paste("C:\\page-", i, ".json", sep = "")

  ## Apply the function to the file corresponding to i
  results.i <- myFunction(page.i, i)

  ## Add the output from the function to a 'master' data frame with the results from page 1 to 3
  all.results <- rbind(all.results, results.i)
}
```

I've also tried to get the lappy() method to work instead of the for() loop, but I hit a blank on that too.  Any help or pointers you can give me would be great.

Many thanks,

J

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read many files in parallel and extract data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578196/read-many-files-in-parallel-and-extract-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` as -

```
filenames <- list.files('path/', pattern = '\\.json$', full.names = TRUE)

result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  page_num <- as.numeric(sub('.*page-(\\d+).*', '\\1', x))
  myFunction(fromJSON(x), page_num)
}))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this seems to be what I needed, but how do I pass the page number as the second argument in myFunction please?  The page number is found at the end of the filename, before ".json".  E.g. "C:\\page-1.JSON"